# How to use PHP Generators in EXACt API Picqer

Tags: php, api, generator

I want to use the PHP Generator to fetch all items, instead of the default 60.
How can use this with the EXACT API of Picqer?

```
$item = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\Item($connection);
$item->getAsGenerator();
$item_array = $item->filterAsGenerator("Class_01 eq 'test' or Class_01 eq 'test2' or Class_01 eq 'test3'");

// Get Exact data with limit
function getLines($file)
{
    ///your code before that
    foreach ($file as $product_item_line) {
      yield $product_item_line;
  }
}

// Loop through each Exact item
foreach (getLines($item_array) as $n => $product_item_line) {
// Fetch all exact item data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on the Exact API or Picqer but I think there are two parts to the answer:

- Use BulkItem i.o. Item. BulkItem has a limit of 1000 and that helps to speed
  things up;
- Imho, you don't need any of the xxxAsGenerator methods. Picqer handles that for you. The code below works and is much shorter. You can then loop through $items and use $item->attributes() for each $item to get access to the details.

```
   $conn = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\BulkItem($connection);
   $items = $conn->filter("Class_01 eq 'test' or Class_01 eq 'test2' or Class_01 eq 'test3'", '', 'ID, Code', ['$top' => 10000]);
```